# WinForms program throwing System.ArgumentException in System.Drawing.dll and I don't know why

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I've written a small program that scans through files in a folder and if they are an image file, the program will check that the image width, height and DPI matches what the user input in a form.

For each image that doesn't match any one of these three categories, the program writes to a text file (comma separated) the filename, and which tests the image failed/passed. Essentially, it ensures that all images in a folder are the dimensions and dpi that the user defines.

Here's the code for the 'scan' method :

```
else
        {
            string[] filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(scanDirTb.Text);

            int i = 0;
            int n = 100;
            string width = widthTb.Text;
            string height = heightTb.Text;
            string dpi = dpiTb.Text;

            foreach (string element in filesInDirectory)
            {
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(filesInDirectory[i]);

                if (i == n)
                {
                    //update the scanned images label every 100 images to show progress
                    scannedImagesLbl.Text = "Images scanned : " + i + "/" + filesInDirectory.Length;
                    n = n + 100;
                    Refresh();
                }

                if (ext.Contains(".jpg") || ext.Contains(".jpeg") || ext.Contains(".gif") || ext.Contains(".bmp") || ext.Contains(".png"))
                {
                    using(Bitmap currentImage = new Bitmap(filesInDirectory[i]))
                    {
                        bool widthMatch  = widthMatches (currentImage, width);
                        bool heightMatch = heightMatches(currentImage, height);
                        bool dpiMatch    = dpiMatches   (currentImage, dpi);

                        if (!widthMatch || !heightMatch || !dpiMatch)
                        {
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filesInDirectory[i]);
                            writeLog(fileName, widthMatch, heightMatch, dpiMatch);
                            i++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            i++;
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            scannedImagesLbl.Text = "Images scanned : " + i + "/" + filesInDirectory.Length;

        }
    }
```

Seems to be working fine - no issues with writing to the file, etc. HOWEVER, I am trying to scan about 21,000 files, of which around 20,950 are images and when I get to image ~11,000 the program throws this exception :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

At the line :

```
                    using(Bitmap currentImage = new Bitmap(filesInDirectory[i]))
```

I've had this issue before, but the cause of that was due to permissions. There should not be any problems with permissions here, all the files are in one folder and no special permissions have been set.

Anyone got an idea of what's causing this exception?

EDIT : Figured this might be important - the program throws this exception EVERY TIME at around 11,000 images through. I've tested this 4 times.

Comment: Could you provide us the value of `filesInDirectory[i]` when the exception occurs?

Comment: filesInDirectory {string[21281]}, i = 11059. I think I'm starting to realise where I messed up

Comment: Nope nevermind. Thought it might be because i was getting incremented somewhere where it wasn't supposed to, but I stepped through and it looks ok... still lost

Comment: Could you still provide us the actual string though?

Comment: Apparently there is something wrong with the particular file/filename at that particular point. You should be looking at it to evaluate the problem.

Comment: This is the value, isn't it? {string[21281]} - from watch

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a 0kb image file... I feel stupid